# Should we use ionic framework for building large scale mobile application?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have plan for build some android application with ionic framework. But I have a question, should we use ionic framework for building large scale mobile application?

Comment: This is really a subjective question. Compare the pros and cons of cross-platform development as against native development. If one out weighs the other, choose it. That being said, I am a _pro native development_ kinda fellow, but can see the advantages of cross-platform development as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop large scale application with ionic also but it is always advisable to develop native apps, i have developed both an ionic app and an native app these are differences you find while doing an hybrid app:

1. Smoothness is a major issue, your app screen looks fragile and apps takes very long time for user touch events like smooth scroll, button clicks etc.
2. UI(Even if you are a rock star in web UI) at the end of the day you are embedding your html pages into an android app, Mobiles with <1GB ram takes lot of time to render page
3. Back button events, you can't hard code back button press and maintain list of screens in backstack(android term) hence you should break head managing user back button press events
4. Memory leakage issues, you don't have any control on this heck
5. How do you handle activity(screen) lifecycle changes( what happens in resume,pause,stop,create,destroy of screen)
6. You are not going to implement best practices of android

So as you are going to build large scale android app, its always advisable to go with native app

Hybrid apps are only for MVP purpose of an idea not for end users. Don't do the mistake of wasting your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean "Large scale" mobile application. If you're talking about the number of users, this depends on the server and Ionic has no effect on this. If you mean you application will do some memory intensive tasks that you should go native of course.

If you're talking about the look and feel for a production app, ionic is good but from my experience, it is not as you would think that it would take half the time instead of developing on 2 platforms. The time needed to tweak it so that it really looks like a native app is important and this assumes that you're really confortable with Javascript.